# zsh: command not found: find

Tags: find, command, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have recently updated my MacOS to Sonoma 14.1.1

Have tired various methods to fix this command to no avail.

I typed this to the terminal

```
find. -name "DS_Store" type f -delete
```

and got this response

```
zsh: command not found: find.
```

I have already tried doing

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:${PATH}
export PATH
```

Comment: There should be a space between `find` and `.`.

Comment: Thank you @tkauls I am not sure why iTerm2 removed the space between the ```find``` and  ```.``` appreciate your help!